# Interact with terminal application Java or C++

Tags: java, terminal

I'm trying to make a GUI that will interact with a terminal-based program, in this case the geth console for Ethereum. I'm able to start it up, but I have no idea how to send commands or retrieve output once it's running.

I've tried other programs, like Vim, but everything is totally separate from my program after it's started and I'm unable to give it any further commands.

After searching StackOverflow and matching solutions together, this is what I've come up with, and it's the closest I've come to success.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        String[] command = {"gnome-terminal", "-e", "vim temp.txt"};

        Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

        BufferedReader reader =  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(proc.getOutputStream()));

        writer.write(":x");
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
    }
}
```

This will start Vim, creating temp.txt, but then Vim just sits open and the writer does nothing.

Is what I'm trying to do even possible?

P.S. I'm okay with C++, but I'd prefer Java for this as I'm more familiar with it.

Comment: Typically, interactive programs aren't run that way. You can read/write to processes, but only stdin/stdout/stderr. If it's a GUI program it'll depend on the OS sending it messages, like mouse clicks, keyboard strokes and such. What exactly are you trying to accomplish? If you simply want to enter commands in the terminal program and read their output, just execute those commands directly.

Comment: I'm researching cryptocurrency and this will eventually become a GUI for Ethereum, which is very similar to Bitcoin. Most of the currently available GUIs are buggy and still in development. One of my team mates is working on bugfixes for one, but I'm trying to start from scratch and make something that's specialized for our needs.

Comment: what do you mean with "the writer does nothing"? Is the amount of written bytes equal to zero?

Comment: I mean vim didn't receive the command.

Comment: you need to put the `-` sign after your `vim` command, apparently. This is no question about java, its about linux bash syntax, you are asking the wrong community. Ask it here : http://superuser.com or possibly even here : http://unix.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

[On the GO-Ethereum Wiki](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/geth#interfaces) it says that it supports:

- a JavaScript Console. You'd have to write the app in JavaScript itself - probably not an option here;
- a JSON RPC server, in which case you'd communicate over a socket, not STDIN/OUT;
- [Commandline Options](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Command-Line-Options), in which case you would

  ```
  String[] command = {"geth", "help" };
  ```